# Unity dash: Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search

Tags: 14.04, unity, unity-dash, lenses

I face with problem

> Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search

When searching in applications. However searching within files or musics etc is ok. Just applications are not found. it even does not try to find anything. No matter what you search, No app at all.

[image: unity dash nothing that matches your search]

Here there is a list of my **attempts**:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unity-scope-home is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

No effect.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-place-applications unity-place-files
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-place-applications
E: Unable to locate package unity-place-files
```

No hope

```
rm ~/.cache -R
unity --reset &
```

Result:

```
[1] 5355
me@mypc:~$ ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated
```

still not working even by logout/login.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

No!

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home unity-scope-loader
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-scope-loader
```

No!

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-scope-home
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to reinstall, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/105 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 565848 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-scope-home_6.8.2+14.04.20131029.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-scope-home (6.8.2+14.04.20131029.1-0ubuntu1) over (6.8.2+14.04.20131029.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-scope-home (6.8.2+14.04.20131029.1-0ubuntu1) ...
```

No effect!

---

**Edit:**

I checked and realized that even other user accounts have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> E: Unable to locate package unity-place-applications
>
> E: Unable to locate package unity-place-files

`unity-place-applications` and `unity-place-files`   are [no more available in Ubuntu 14.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/unity-place-applications) instead use `unity-lens-applications` and `unity-lens-files` which is founded in universe repository, so first enable it(if it's disabled for some reason else skip it to the last command)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Now update software sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install it :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications

sudo apt-get install unity-lens-files
```

<del>Try to do this:

    mkdir local.OLD
    mkdir gnome.OLD
    mv .local/share/applications/*.desktop local.OLD/
    mv .gnome/apps/*.desktop gnome.OLD/

Then logout, login and check the result now.</del>

Comment: `setsid unity` just restarted the unity but did not affect application searching.

Comment: Do you mean that it must be problem of the others as well?

Comment: I ran [this](http://pastebin.com/gvwLkhdk) and [that](http://pastebin.com/RrVG89fS). I  will restart unity and see what will happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar problem as yours: unity-scope-loader crash was reported, dash app search failed to find any app, and even the gnome-terminal crashed silently when run some commands.

Finally I solved it by correcting the permissions of the /tmp folder, here is how:

1)Check your permissions on the /tmp folder.

ls -la /tmp

and I found the write permission of . is removed for non-root users.

2) make /tmp writable for everyone
cd /tmp

sudo chmod 1777 .

Now everything looks OK

Why the write permission of /tmp is removed? perhaps because I accidentally untared a root file system into /tmp folder before.

Comment: "I checked and realized that even other user accounts have the same problem."  --- this applies to my case too, so I am sure it is not related to the configurations under the home directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had almost forgotten this question. I am not sure if changing permission of root is a correct job.  for me the status of the tmp folder is `drwxrwxrwt   7 root root  4096 Mar  2 21:47 tmp` .  At the moment, I don't face with this problem anymore. So it is hard to say if it could fix my problem. So I leave it to the feedback from the other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Applications scope had somehow been disabled. So, I clicked the A-shaped icon at the bottom of the dash to go to the "Search applications" tab, clicked on same icon under "Dash plugins", then clicked enable.

When I switched back to the home tab, unity froze up. I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> thinking I'd restart it from there, but when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>'d back check on it again, it restarted on its own.

After this, things seemed back to normal, at least on that front. But, as usual, the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 broke many things, which I guess I'll be working on for a few days yet.      ◔_◔