# How to enable Ubuntu 14.04 Unity to show the installed applications?

Tags: 14.04, unity

After a lot of fiddling and fidgeting to get back internet connection on my Desktop running Ubuntu 14.04, I find that the Ubuntu  dash shows only files and folders etc. The installed applications are not showing up. Have tried many suggestions that have come up in various threads, in vain. Please help with suggestions

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642725/unity-dash-sorry-there-is-nothing-that-matches-your-search/642731?noredirect=1#comment920352_642731

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. You want to be able to search for "installed applications" from your `dash` OR You want to see the list of all installed applications?

Answer (score 0):

To see your installed applications, Open `Ubuntu Software Center` :

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

Click on `Installed` , which will show you the list of all applications.

[image: Installed - Ubuntu Software Center]

To see other installations, click on the drop-down arrow next to `Installed`.

Answer (score 0):

on the bottom of the dash overlay there are  clickable icons indicating what are you filtering to show on the dash, names of each sub section will appear when you hover over these icons. Make sure you haven't typed any search queries in the dash search bar.